How can I download more than 10,000 records of data with derived columns as csv or excel from workshop button group?
I have a function that can add new columns to object and used in workshop to download data as CSV. However the limit on object with derived columns is 10,000. Is there a way to download more data (like somewhere below 100k records same limit as regular limit without derived columns) than 10,000 limit with derived columns?
I tried using transform table in workshop and materializations in quiver but I was not able to output it as object set. I want the output to be in the form of an object set so that I can use it in button group widget. I even tried to create a function to take 10,000 chunks or less per data but it exceeds execution time limit.
Note: I have configured button to download data in workshop.
